# Webpage is not displaying anything while Running with selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automate one of the web application using the selenium with c#, while executing the script code is running but web page is displaying completely unloaded only URL is displaying in browser.

I tried page load time out and wait as well but it seems that doesn't affect the browser actions

```cs
void launchBrowser() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver("D:\\csharp");
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}

void launchUrl(String url) {
    driver.Url = url;
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

It should display the home page of my application,but it is just displaying the url and rest of the things are white

Comment: What URL are you trying to go to?

Comment: Sorry can't share that

Comment: Which version of chrome and chrome driver are you using?

Comment: Chrome 76.0.3809.100 and ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68

Comment: Is it working for other URLs, if yes then do you have any specific browser setting which needs to be done in order for browser to work properly with URL or maybe some proxy settings or something. In that case you can make use of the DesiredCapabilities class (Options/ChromeOptions class).

Comment: I Also launched the other URL with same settings, in that case it is working very much proper,So i don't think that i have changed any settings and didn't use of any cap and options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);